# In outlook Item send event handler , click the send button error thrown while Message sending

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In Outlook New message compose or Edit the outlook event ,send button click ,(By use The Item send event handler In outlook add-ins) , click the send button this error thrown [image]

But I want this , when i click the send button that one is trigger on my outlook add-ins command.js file , it not trigger anything in this file , this error thrown

In outlook add-ins manifest.xml file use this code for item send event handler

```
 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
        <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateSubjectAndCC" />
      </ExtensionPoint>``
```

this mentioned function name called on my command.js file ,but inside the function not trigger anything , it shown on outlook info bar error

**Notes : My outlook add-ins developed by using javascript language**

Any thoughts about this Please share me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I have the same error, my add-in is hosted within a URL mentioned (localhost:3000), but I still got the error, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the `OfficeJS` runtime can't locate the function mentioned in the add-in's manifest file. Make sure the add-in is hosted within a URL mentioned in the manifest file. Also you may try to run [the sample add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) available on GitHub.

Comment: Okay , Thank you

Comment: I have the same error, my add-in is hosted within a URL mentioned (https://localhost:3000), but I still got the error, did you solve the issue @TamilarasanRajamanickam?

Comment: Are you able to access the js file in a web browser?